# curl command works in powershell, but not with python subprocess.run()

Tags: python, curl, subprocess

I execute a curl command to fetch an html, containing a word meaning in powershell and it works as expected.
Then I want to execute it with python with subprocess.run(), it returns no errors and I see that the arguments in run() are parsed correctly, but the returned page is the "word not found" page of the website, instead of the page that curl returns in powershell. I want to get the same results as if I execute the command normally in powershell or terminal.

```
    import sys, subprocess
    response = subprocess.run(["curl", f"http://rechnik.info/{sys.argv[1]}", "-o", "query.html"], encoding='utf-8', capture_output=True)
    print(response)
    exit()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Comment: @Stati Kosev - I can't reproduce. How do you run the code?

Comment: i run it either in pycharm or powershell
update: when I tried the same goal on linux, I found out that it works perfectly with os.system, which was the first method I tried on windows as well. Seems to me it's some problem on windows and I suppose on linux it will work with subprocess too

Answer (score 0):

sometimes on windows `curl` is not installed. try using `reqursts` insteade so it will work on every OS.